# buscar fecha en lista de fechas

Tags: python, date

Tengo una lista de fechas que tiene formato datetime.date(año,mes,día).
quiero saber la posición que tiene una **fechax** (que tambien tiene el formato datetime.date(año,mes,día) en la **lista** con el siguiente código: `posicion = lista.index(fechax)`.

python me arroja el error:

> ValueError: datetime.date(año, mes, dia) is not in list

El tema es que tanto la lista como la fecha buscada tienen el mismo formato y me aseguré que esa fechax estuviera en la lista por supuesto.

¿Qué puede estar pasando? o ¿la función el método index no funciona con fechas?

EDIT:

```
Wb = load_workbook(filename = 'C:\ICP.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb["Simple"] 
fecha_icp=[(c.value).date() for c in sheet_ranges['A'][3:3804]]#.date() no agrega tiempo solo la fecha.
```

Con este codigo obtengo fechas d eun excel en donde estan con formato de fecha. para armar la lista leo el valor con .date() para no agregar horas ni minutos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así como se ve en la imagen es como se ve la lista en python. luego ocupo este codigo:`v = icp_value.index(valuation_date)`.
la variable valuation_date la ingreso así :

```
valuation_date= input('ingrese la fecha de valorizacion en formato yyyy-mm-dd')# ingresar fecha de contrato

valuation_date= dt.datetime.strptime(valuation_date.rstrip(), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

y en python se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

como ven, la fecha buscada y la lista tienen el mismo formato y la formula no funciona.

les dejo el excel:https://www.dropbox.com/s/1762eowf6gs91q9/ICP.xlsx?dl=0

saludos,

Comment: Podrias colocar tu codigo para ver cual ese el error.

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo [mcve], no debes tener ese problema si la fecha existe: `lista = [datetime.date(2017, 5, 4),
         datetime.date(2017, 10, 14)]`, `print(lista.index(datetime.date(2017, 10, 14)))`.

Comment: @eyllanesc , FJsevilla, edite la pregunta con mas información.

Comment: @Richie Por favor sube el .xlsx a dropbox, drive o similares y comparte el enlace para poder probar directamente tu codigo

Comment: @eyllanesc subí el xlsx!

Comment: A mi si me funciona correctamente

Comment: Para `2017-10-23` obtengo 3780

Comment: Confirmo lo que comenta eyllanesc, funciona sin problemas... P.D uso `openpyxl` para leer el xlsx. Para `2017-10-13` se obtiene `3774` como índice.

Comment: que raro. podrian poner su codigo solo para checkear please!

Comment: Richie he creado una "respuesta" temporalmente para que compares el código, aunque es el que tu agregas... Es raro, algo se nos escapa.

Comment: encontré el error. al usar el index estaba al escrito el nombre de la lista -.- . Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En principo no haces nada incorrecto, si usas Openpyxl para caragar el xlsx no debes tener ningún problema mientras la fecha exista:

```
import datetime as dt
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook(filename = 'C:\ICP.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb["Simple"] 
fecha_icp=[(c.value).date() for c in sheet_ranges['A'][3:3804]]
valuation_date= input('ingrese la fecha de valorizacion en formato yyyy-mm-dd')
valuation_date= dt.datetime.strptime(valuation_date.rstrip(), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
posicion = fecha_icp.index(valuation_date)
print(posicion)
```

Ante la posibilidad de que se ingrese una fecha que realmente no esté en la lista puedes tratar la excepción de forma adecuada a tus necesidades:

```
try:
    posicion = fecha_icp.index(valuation_date)
except ValueError:
    position = None
```

Ten en cuenta que esto es válido si solo quieres el indice del primer elemento que encuentre, ya que si tienes una fecha repetida solo retornará el índice de la primera. En estos casos se puede recurrir a `enumerate` y compresión de listas para obtener un iterable con los indice de todas las ocurrencias:

```
posicion = [i for i, fecha in enumerate(fecha_icp) if fecha == valuation_date]
```